# Issue observed with Android app developed using phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I have developed `Android application`using `Phonegap framework` with Eclipse pulgin. am not gettting any error in `Eclipse` but when i'm running the app am able to see the blank app screen.So can someone help me out this issue..

Sample app developed using this [link](http://phonegap.com/start/#android)

Please comment asap..

Code:

Java File ----------

```
     package com.phonegap; 
     import com.phonegap.*; 
     import android.os.Bundle; 

    public class HelloworldActivity extends DroidGap 
    { 
       @Override 
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       {   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/www/helloworld.html"); 
        } 
     }
```

Comment: Java File
----------
package com.phonegap;

import com.phonegap.*;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class HelloworldActivity extends DroidGap {
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/www/helloworld.html");
    }
}
Html
----
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>PhoneGap</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>

Comment: lolz not here...I mean in the original question

Comment: I followed the step by step procedure given in the above link..

Comment: Have you done everything correctly?  I mean setting up of the project etc

Comment: ya the entire thing was done bt i dono how to run that ruby command vl there b any issue with tat

Comment: see this link : http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/phonegap/creating-an-android-hello-world-application-with-phonegap .. it works fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your loadUrl, you should use:

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html"); // Singular android_asset, not assets
```

Comment: Hey in my project i have folder name as assets thats why y loaded like tat.ok come to ur url its also nt working..

Comment: The folder is names `assets`, but in the URL you should use `android_asset`.
PS: Characters are free, use them all for readability!